# How do i use SetPixel on a new Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The code:

```
Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);
foreach (Point s in CommonList)
{
    w.WriteLine("The following points are the same" + s);
    newbmp.SetPixel(s.X, s.Y, Color.Red);
}
w.Close();
newbmp.Save(@"c:\newbmp\newbmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
newbmp.Dispose();
```

When it's trying to `Save` the new bmp I'm getting exception on the line:

```
newbmp.Save(@"c:\newbmp\newbmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The exception is:

> ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: The problem is not that you manipulate the pixel and saves it. Does the "newbmp" folder exist? Since it's a save error there is two possible things. The image format is invalid or the path is invalid.

Comment: No it doesn't. Your code works fine. But indeed maybe your path is wrong..

Comment: Right there was a mistake with the path name. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you have such save errors, you must make sure that the path where you want to save exists and you have the necessary privileges to effectuate your save.